# How to display all titles from Json file in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have this function:

```
function: function getSimilar() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../Content/test.txt",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var similar;
            var id = parseInt(document.getElementById('similar').getAttribute('data-id')) || 0;
            if(similar) {
                document.querySelector('#similar').innerHTML = similar.Title;
                document.getElementById('similar').setAttribute('data-id', similar.id);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.error('Error in AJAX call');
            console.error(data);
        }
    });
}
```

And a Json file with article titles:

```
[{
  "id": 0,
  "Title": "First Blog",
  "Content": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy  has been the industry's standard dummy text ever ."
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "Title": "Second Blog",
  "Content": "industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the ."
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "Title": "Third Blog",
  "Content": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum ."
}]
```

I want to display titles in one of my html divs called similar
Could anyone help me with it?
I suppose i should create a list in html.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using jQuery AND plain JavaScript?

Comment: Why not? TA TA TAAAAAUUUUMMMMMM!

Comment: putvande if you have a better code maybe you could share?

Comment: Jquery **IS** plain javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use loop to iterate over all items received in order to form list of items that will be added to the DOM. To create bulk of new DOM elements I prefer to collect them all in some string buffer and then add at once - it is bit more faster, but not necessary. Your code may be something like this:

**JavaScript**

```
function getSimilar() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../Content/test.txt",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          var i, l, list;
          if(data && data.length > 0) {
            list = ['<ul>'];
            for(i=0,l=data.length; i<l; i++) {
              list.push('<li data-id="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].Title + '</li>');
            }
            list.push('</ul>');
            $('#similar').html(list.join(''));
          }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.error('Error in AJAX call');
            console.error(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/O6YTXo9nNGlqs7rsu8PF?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
 var data = [{
            "id": 0,
            "Title": "First Blog",
            "Content": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy  has been the industry's standard dummy text ever ."
        }, {
            "id": 1,
            "Title": "Second Blog",
            "Content": "industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the ."
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "Title": "Third Blog",
            "Content": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum ."
        }];

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#similar").append($("<span/>", { html: data[i].Title }));
            $("#similar").append($("<span/>", { html: data[i].Content }));
            $("#similar").append("<br/>");
        }
```

**Edit**

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../Content/test.txt",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $("#similar").append($("<span/>", { html: data[i].Title, "data-id": data[i].id }));

                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.error('Error in AJAX call');
                console.error(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: My json file is in different folder and i am already using it within another function. I cannot create var in json file.

Comment: @user2976554, Put the for loop in success callback

Comment: `$("#similar").attr("data-id", data[i].id);` line is ambiguous.

Comment: I will suggest you to store data-id with span

Answer (score 0):

If you have the jSon in the response , ie in data the you can get all the title as following

```
 success: function (data) {
          for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           $("#similar").append($("<span/>", { html: data.d[i].Title, "data-id": data.d[i].id }));
           }
```

Is this what you are looking for?